# How to determine if sql script is executed parallel or not?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am wondering if this sql is going to execute in parallel or not? This is going to be a new sql stored procedure, which will call other three procedures. I want every procedure to start when the previous one has completed.

```
BEGIN

IF (new_times_flag = TRUE) THEN
    CALL PROCEDURE1(dateFor);
ELSE 
    UPDATE kt_zones_timeslots_settings SET date_for = dateFor WHERE date_for = oldDateFor;
END IF;
    
CALL PROCEDURE2(dateFor);
CALL PROCEDURE3(dateFor);

END
```

I have read how does sql works in procedure, but I can't find answer of this case exactly. Every next procedure is dependent on the previous so that why I want them to work not in parallel. Something more, these procedures are consist of creating temporary tables, updates, deletes, selects and inserts. I was thinking about something like this (transaction), too:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            IF (new_times_flag = TRUE) THEN
                CALL CalcActualZoneUTR(dateFor);
            ELSE 
                UPDATE kt_zones_timeslots_settings SET date_for = dateFor WHERE date_for = oldDateFor;
            END IF;
                
            CALL MakeRealShifts(dateFor);
            CALL InsertSeparateShifts(dateFor);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK;
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: without special instructions, only single queries can execute in parallel , statements in a batch do not.

Comment: So, this procedures are not going to execute in parallel? I was wondering if it isn't better to put all the procedure in transaction?

Comment: What DBMS is this about?

Comment: It is RDBMS - MariaDB.

Comment: Transactions are used for an entirely different reason.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just recommend it because I do not want to execute all sql if there is a problem in the beginning. Maybe I should prevent parallel processing in my php and yii code, because I do not see how to do it in sql..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls in the procedure are executed one by one, not in parallel.

Comment: And it means that if the previous call did not finished the new will not start, doesn't it?

Comment: The `InsertSeparateShifts` will execute after the `MakeRealShifts` has completed.

Comment: Thank you, this is the exact answer I was waiting for!